# Optimization of custom algorithm to matrix iteration

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

I am not the author of below function, but I am trying to optimize it or make it more simple.
Do you have any idea how I can make it more efficient?

I am translating this code to C++, so I am rather thinking about general ideas, not Python-specific optimizations.

At the beginning, I thought that this should end with an infinite loop, but when after long hour analysis I understand that lastiter will be false when no new points will be added to new set.
It means that all points above threshold were "visited" (added to keep set).

```
def filter_strong_edges(gradient, width, height, low, high):
    # Keep strong edges
    keep = set()
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            if gradient[x, y] > high:
                keep.add((x, y))

    # Keep weak edges next to a pixel to keep
    lastiter = keep
    while lastiter:
        newkeep = set()
        for x, y in lastiter:
            for a, b in ((-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (0, -1), (0, 1), (1, -1), (1, 0), (1, 1)):
                if gradient[x + a, y + b] > low and (x+a, y+b) not in keep:
                    newkeep.add((x+a, y+b))
        keep.update(newkeep)
        lastiter = newkeep

    return list(keep)
```

Comment: If I understand this right, you are basically doing a flood-fill, starting from all the `> high` positions ans spreading over all the `> low` positions, right?

Comment: Might be simpler using a plain DFS or BSF with a stack or queue, but probably not faster.

Comment: Do you have the exact formula for `gradient[.]` ?

Comment: There are different implementations on this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill#:~:text=Flood%20fill%2C%20also%20called%20seed,in%20a%20multi%2Ddimensional%20array.  There is especially scanline fill that would be faster because every pixel is checked only once whereas yours might check some multiple times.